# how to start up dialer from a button click in a page within a xamarin forms webview control

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using a PCL project. In this I am loading a url in a Xamarin forms webview container. This url has a button with a telephone number in it. When I load it in the same url in the phone's chrome browser, it brings up the dialer, however, when I load the url in a `Xamarin.Forms.WebView` control I get an error `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

This is my code in the xaml page. This is a Xamarin.Forms.Webview control here.

```
<WebView x:Name="wvCntr" Source="{Binding TheWebUrl, Mode=TwoWay }"
                    WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000" />
```

Then in my Xaml.cs page, I have this code

```
public class WContainer : WebViewClient
{
    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
    {
        //What code here?
        return true;
    }
}
```

How is supposed to work? The Xaml page has `Xamarin.Forms.Webview` and the code behind I am using an `Android.Webkit.Webview`. I am not able to make the connect here and then get the code which actually pulls up the dialer. I am using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015.

Any help or code appreciated.

Comment: Could you give an example of the uri schema/format you using?

Comment: Have you tried something like this: <a href="intent:+27837163221#Intent;scheme=tel;end"> Take a QR code </a>

Comment: I dont have access to the code in the URL to change it. This is what is there currently `<a href="tel:+12315687" class="btn btn-primary">
Call Doctor
</a>`

Comment: Is your "ShouldOverrideUrlLoading" being called?

Comment: No its not.The examples I am seeing online have a class where the `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading` is overloaded. In that, the following method is called `StartActivity(intent)`. I dont know how this method can be called. Its part of this class `MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity` The two have no connection.

Comment: Also, the `ShouldOverrideUrlLoading` method takes a parameter of type `Android.Webkit.WebView` while my Xamarin forms project uses a `Xamarin.Forms.WebView` control. How will this work together? Can't seem to drop `Android.Webkit.WebView` control on a Xamarin forms content page.